# Rendering flash and with a custom fetch request instead of Inertia.js request

Tags: reactjs, inertiajs

I'm using Inertia.js with react. I have a [MUI datatable](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid) with a switch component for each row. When I toggle the switch component using inertia js everything works fine. The record's state is udpated in the DB, a flash message it visible and the datatable shows the switch component in the correct state.

The problem however, is that after the request is made the component is rerendered and the MUI datatable will refresh and move rows around. The MUI datatable has it's own scrollbar as I am have set the max height to `sx={{ maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 200px)" }}`. Based on the [inertia js docs here](https://inertiajs.com/scroll-management#scroll-regions), I would need to add `scroll-region` attribute to the container that has the css overflow setup. But I have no idea how I would do that as I'm just using a prebuilt component from MUI.

But I have figured out a way to make this work. My solution so far is to do a manual fetch request without using inertia js, dispatch an event "flash" with the flash message. Then my flash component, will listen for this event and render the flash.

So the question here - Is this the right approach? Is there a better way to handle rendering flash messages from inertia js when making requests with fetch/axios instead of inertia js router. Perhaps I need to use a state management lib like zustand, but I was hoping to keep things simple with inertia js.

Here's my click event when I click on a Switch component.

```
import { patch } from "@rails/request.js";


const handleToggle = (id, checked) => {
  patch(`/events/${id}/toggle_locked`, {
    body: { locked: !checked },
    contentType: "application/json",
    responseKind: "json",
  });

  // flash message event
  const event = new CustomEvent("flash", {
    detail: {
      message: `Event has been ${checked ? "locked" : "unlocked"}!`,
    },
  });

  window.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

here is my flash component:

```
import { usePage } from "@inertiajs/react";
import { Alert, Button, Snackbar, Stack } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Flash() {
  const { flash } = usePage().props;

  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState(flash.message);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMessage(flash.message);
  }, [flash]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("flash", (e) => {
      setMessage(e.detail.message);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleClose = (
    event?: React.SyntheticEvent | Event,
    reason?: string
  ) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setMessage(null);
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Snackbar
        open={message !== null}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
          {message}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```